# Should an object save to the database on setting property (e.g. a Blog Post object)

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing

I am beginning to get into more OO PHP and also writing tests for that objects. My main question is: if I have a `Blog_Post` object, and I call `$post->setCategory( 'Foo' )`, should doing that save to the database directly?

The reason I ask is for unit testing, I often don't want to use the DB for these kind of things because that's not what I am testing.

I have seen people suggest doing something like

```
function __construct( PDO $db )
```

to pass in the database object to be used, then use  mock when testing. However, I really don't like the idea of having instantiate my database objects all the time by whatever is calling the Blog_Post class.

This is in the scope of WordPress, which does not have an OO approach fundamentally - with my current Blog_Post, the setter method would just call the DB (via a global $wpdb!! (i know!)).

Really I wanted to know, what's the general pattern that is the path of least resistance with something like this. Would Blog_Post just write it's self, or would one maybe put on a "save()" method to actually push all set properties to the DB? Or perhaps set a flag on teh object "setSaveToDB(false)" before calling the setter.

Thanks, hope this make some sense!

Comment: Short answer: No. Delegate loading saving to another layer.

Comment: @hakre thanks, just what I was looking for - a straight answer :)

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Delegate loading, saving to another layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have any kind of performance, then using a ->save() function on the object is preferable to saving whenever a property is set. If you write to the database every time a property is set then an object with 7 properties will write 7 times to the db, if you have a save function then only one write will be used for all 7 properties. Since opening the db connection is the slowest function of a db you will want to minimize the amount of separate read/writes. In general terms, opening the connection to the db and writing one row takes about the same time as opening a connection and writing 100000 rows. SQL is fast when handling large data sets, but opening the connection and finding the right place to read/write is quite slow.

Hope this helps :-)